Como uso o webdriver manager no Selenium python?
Quero aprender Selenium python e estou tentando usar o WebDriverManager para instalar e atualizar drives automaticamente. Seguindo as instruções de sites, importei vários módulos e tentei inicializar o navegador, mas dá erro. No final tem isso aqui: bla

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Failed to create Chrome process.
Stacktrace

. Segue o meu código:
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.Chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

E depois:
servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= Servico)

Quando eu executo isso o terminal retorna erros e mensagens confusos e o navegador não abre, como esperado.
Esse é todo o código. Como eu resolvo isso para continuar a estudar Selenium? Caso não consiga usar o webdriver manager, vou baixar o driver do chrome manualmente, como antigamente.
Segue imagens do problema.
O código que eu escrevi ---
o que o terminal retorna quando eu tento executar/erro ---
um monte de outros de erros confusos retornados

Qual mensagem de erro?

Vou colocar o erro certo e também algumas imagens dele depois. Sabe se o problema pode ter a ver com eu usar dentro de um ambiente virtual o webdriver manager? Uso virtualenv. Obrigado.

Olá Angelo. Sem o erro não é possível saber.

editei a pergunta.
